# How to get service principal by client ID in javascript

Tags: azure

I have registered an application in azure portal, I need to get the service principal Id using the registered application ID in my javascript application. But I could not find the API to do this job. I try to using  azure-graph api, but the list function of ServicePrincipals interface needs a special permission which is not applicable. Is there any easy way to get service principal by application ID and secret?

Answer (score 1):

Azure App **Client ID is identical to Service Principal ID** if you created this app in your tenant. In case of multitenant app more principals will be created since App is 1:many relationship to service principal objects but they will have the same ID too.

[image]

Showing azure ad application using CLI

```
az ad app show --id ""
```

[image]

Showing azure ad service principal using CLI

```
az ad sp show --id ""
```

[image]

Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#application-and-service-principal-relationship

Comment: service principal id is different application Id: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066287/azure-service-principal-id-vs-application-id.  commdnd  az ad app show --id "" is show app. for service principal you should use command az ad sp show --id

Comment: The appId property on the app and sp is the same always, regardless if it's single tenant or not. The objectId of the SP is always a unique id, separate from the objectId of the app object. The objectId is also different in each tenant where the app is registered.