# List Azure Active Directory Applications Enabled for Sign In

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to get a list of Azure AD Enterprise Applications configured for Single Sign On.

It is fairly easy to call `Get-AzureAdApplication -All $true`, however this list includes Service Principals.

In the properties of the Enterprise Application within the Azure Portal, I see that there is an `Enabled for Users to Sign In` toggle setting, however I do not see that property exposed via the results of the `Get-AzureAdApplication`.

How do I return a list of *just* the Enterprise Application that have this toggle set to Yes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean about get just Enterprise Application without service principals. If you want to get the Enterprise Application, you just need to use this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) shown as below:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true
```

After running the command above, we can get the list of apps under the Enterprise Application in Azure Active Directory --> Enterprise applications(on azure portal). Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066287/azure-service-principal-id-vs-application-id) which may help us to know more about the relationship of azure registration apps, enterprise app and service principal.

For the requirement of get the Enterprise applications with `Enabled for users to sign-in` enabled, we can just use the command below:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object{$_.AccountEnabled -eq $true}
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks for the links; it helped me get a better under standing of the Application/ServicePrincipal/AppRegistration concepts. Let me clarify what I am after: I am looking to identify any AppRegistrations in our tenant which are configured for Single Sign On; specifically, I am looking for SAML based SSO. I am assuming I can  retrieve the list of AppRegistrations with a ReplyToUrls count > 0. Is there a way to list all of the AppRegistrations and the type of SSO they are facilitating?

Comment: Hi @codechurn I'm afraid we can't get the list of registration apps with the filter of their SSO.