# Assign the Service Connection User a role through ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-configuration

We just started recently using App Configuration Service in Azure for some of our applications.

As part of the setup, we removed Access Keys as a possible authentication method. This works pretty well, we have assigned dataowner rights to our team so that they can manage the service and everyone is happy.

We came up with the brilliant idea of using the app config service in our build and release yaml pipelines. We found a suitable task, but the user that is attached to the service connection that we use in Azure Devops to deploy to Azure does not have the rights to access the configuration store.

We want to be able to assign this right in the arm template we created for the app config service. The issue though is that we cannot find the principle id assigned to that user.

Honestly, I am not that experienced with AAD, so I am probably missing something here. The ServicePrincipleId does not work, whenever I try to use it, azure tells me that that user does not exist. I get redirected to an app-registration page whenever I try to manage the service connection, which I don't understand either.

Next steps for me will be to get our admin to manually assign this right to the Service Connection User and see if I can extract the principle Id from that role assignment.

My question(s) would be, why doesn't the service principle work? How do I extract the principle id from the service connection?

Comment: If you go to the service connection in AzDO you should see an option/link there to "Manage Service Principal" - from there you can get the objectId.  If that doesn't unblock you, share the roleAssignment code that isn't working.

Comment: It will give you the client_id but then you could look up the objectid quiet easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try below steps?

1. In Azure DevOps, go to the project that contains your target pipeline. In the lower-left corner, select Project settings.
2. Select Service connections.
3. Select Manage Service Principal.
4. From there, you should be able to find the objectId of your Service Principal, which uniquely identifies your SP.

Also these posts are great resources to learn about AAD Apps and Service Principals:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals
2. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066287/azure-service-principal-id-vs-application-id#:~:text=objectId%20will%20be%20a%20unique,will%20be%20same%20as%20appId%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066287/azure-service-principal-id-vs-application-id#:%7E:text=objectId%20will%20be%20a%20unique,will%20be%20same%20as%20appId%20).

Comment: The problem was that I was missing "principleType". For some reason, as soon as I added   "principalType": "ServicePrincipal" to the arm template, it started working.