# Azure Entra ID |

Tags: azure, microsoft-entra-id

I have a doubt, i am new to azure entra id and i am trying to register the application. I understand from the document that when you register the application and application object and a service principal object is also created.I have registered an app and i see three different ids

- a) Application (client) ID : ab79e7d6-7b69XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
- b) On the overview page i see object id:
  0862e661-cfba-4f94XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
- c) When i click on "Managed application" , i see different object id
  : 16742ff3-f903XXXXXXX

I am really confused which is the application object , which is the service principal object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Application Object ID** is the object ID of the Entra ID application:

[image]

**Application Client ID** is the ID of the application to perform operations against the specific instance of the application.

[image]

**Service principal object ID** is the object ID of the managed application/Enterprise application:

When you click on managed application you will find the Service principal object ID:

[image]

**Note** that: Application ID of the Service principal/managed application/Enterprise application and Microsoft Entra ID application ID will be same.

**In your case,** 0862e661-cfba-4f94XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is the object ID of the Microsoft Entra application and 16742ff3-f903XXXXXXX object ID of the Service principal.

**References:**

[What are Azure TenantId, ClientId (Application Id) and ObjectId? | by Jiangong Sun | Medium](https://jiangong-sun.medium.com/what-are-azure-tenantid-clientid-application-id-and-objectid-3d65de5545c8) by Jiangong Sun

[Azure: Service Principal ID vs Application ID - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066287/azure-service-principal-id-vs-application-id) by Rohit Saigal

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just one doubt, when i ran "az ad sp list" command, i am getting following response : "servicePrincipalNames": [
      "ab79e7d6-7b69-49ea-XXXXXXXXX"
    ],
    "servicePrincipalType": "Application", . I have checked "ab79e7d6-7b69-49ea-XXXXXXXXX" is mentioned as a client id, then why it is showing as a service principal in the output

Comment: Yes you are listening service principles az ad sp list lists the service principles and client id is same for service principal and azure ad app

Comment: Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/oYEVSla.png)